# HQL Join 2 Tables and One not related

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, groovy, hql

Using Grails 2.3.7, I want to make a Query that involes 2 linked tables (has Many and belongsTo) with one unmapped table.

The domains class looks like:

```
class A {
 hasMany[b:B]

 long client

}

Class B {
 belongsTo[a:A]

 idClassC
}

Class C {
 long idClassC

 String description
}
```

It's posible to bring all the objects A that has B and descrption in class C is like a parameter using HQL

I was able to make an SQL query without any troubles, but I have a problem when translating to HQL.

The SQL Query is:

```
 SELECT * FROM A AS a LEFT JOIN B AS b ON a.id = b.idA LEFT JOIN C as c ON b.idClassC=c.id AND c.concepto like '%parameter%';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `s` is not associated with any table in your SQL.

Comment: @Sérgio Michels Sorry, a little typing error. It's c.concept, not s.

Comment: try something like "from A a join a.b b where b.description like '%TEST%'"

Comment: @user3870806 If your relation is not mapped, you cannot do that with HQL. Why you cannot map it?

Comment: @Sérgio Michels The domain class was incorrect from the begining, and now I'm unable to modify it due to the nature of the project.

Comment: @user3870806 Then do two queries hehe

Comment: @Sérgio Michels Yep, hehe, It was the easiest way I solve it...